# Uncaught Error: Class 'Discord\Client' not found PHP

Tags: php, discord

I am working with Php and "Discord". Right now, I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Discord\Client' not found",But in my "src folder

Client library exists, I have "Vendor" and "src" folders, and `client.php` is there. Here is my code - where I am going wrong?

```
<?php
include __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Discord\Discord;
use Discord\Parts\Interactions\Command\Command; // Please note to use this correct namespace!
use Discord\Client;
use Discord\Parts\Interaction;
use Discord\Parts\Choices;
$client = new Client([
    'public_key' => 'b81678ce3e98ff78f9387c3cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'uri' => '0.0.0.0:80', // if you want the client to listen on a different URI
    'logger' => $logger, // different logger, default will write to stdout
    'loop' => $loop, // reactphp event loop, default creates a new loop
    'socket_options' => [], // options to pass to the react/socket instance, default empty array
]);
```

Comment: The error clearly show Discord is not loaded run `composer update` and try if not solved then run `composer require team-reflex/discord-php`. I hope it will work. Also remove the  2nd line `include 'vendor/autoload.php';`  because 1st line already include autoload file.

Comment: have you done : composer require team-reflex/discord-php ? Is your php script in same directory of the vendor dir ?

Comment: @svgta : yes my script and vendor both are in root ( same directory)

Comment: @MuradAli: i am getting following message now

Root composer.json requires team-reflex/discord-php ^7.1 -> satisfiable by team-reflex/discord-php[v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3].
    - team-reflex/discord-php[v7.1.0, ..., v7.1.3] require nesbot/carbon ^2.38 -> found nesbot/carbon[2.38.0, ..., 2.59.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^1.18).

Comment: @Mike Remove composer.json and run `composer require team-reflex/discord-php`

Comment: @MuradAli still getting same error

Comment: It says root `composer.json` remove the one in root.

Comment: @MuradAli: yes i did but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
$client = new Discord([
    'token' => 'b81678ce3e98ff78f9387c3cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
]);
```

Instead of client because library [team-reflex/discord-php](https://github.com/discord-php/DiscordPHP) using Discord class instead of Client in direct interaction.

[Here](https://discord-php.github.io/DiscordPHP/#basics) you can find the use cases.